# Output file not being generated

Tags: python, binary, output, ascii

so i was coding something to convert charactors to ascii decimal and binary values that bit works fine but i wanted to add a option to have the output saved into a file called output.txt i have tried it on its own (and its worked) without trying to print out the c varable but when i have the binary varable it doest even create a file.

```
if file.lower == "y":
    char = input("Please enter text: ") #asking user for text to be converted

    for letter in char:   # creating a loop for every charater(s)
        deciminal = ord(letter) #getting decimal value
        binary = bin(deciminal) #getting binary value but has b in it
        a = bin(deciminal)      
        b = bin(deciminal)[2:]   #found this to remove b dont know how it works
        c = b.zfill(8)
        print()
        print(
        "",letter,
        "=",
        f"{Fore.BLUE}Deciminal:",   # printing results in easy to read format
        deciminal,
        f"{Fore.MAGENTA}Binary:",
        c
        )
        f = open("output.txt", "w")
        f.write(c)
        f.close()
        


        print()

else:
    


    char = input("Please enter text: ") #asking user for text to be converted

    for letter in char:   # creating a loop for every charater(s)
        deciminal = ord(letter) #getting decimal value
        binary = bin(deciminal) #getting binary value but has b in it
        a = bin(deciminal)      
        b = bin(deciminal)[2:]   #found this to remove b dont know how it works
        c = b.zfill(8)
        print()


        print(
            "",letter,
            "=",
            f"{Fore.BLUE}Deciminal:",   # printing results in easy to read format
            deciminal,
            f"{Fore.MAGENTA}Binary:",
            c
            )


        print()
```

Comment: So it works without the print statement? Are you getting an error? Are those `Fore` values working as you expect? Maybe try removing parts of the print statement until it works to find the problem.

Comment: The print statement works fine with all the colour it's the bit underneath that I think is the issue the f.write() bit

Comment: It works for me if I remove the print statement. What value are you testing?